# html converted table in wordpress too wide and doesn't fit in full width page template

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I am trying to paste a xlsx file in wordpress with some problems. I finally used google docs to convert it to html and it  looks exactly as it should be only the content does not fill in the page:

http://www.biomayeutika.org/que/

Here it is the beginning of the table. I know it may be a lame question but I don't know better.

```
&nbsp;
</p>

<p>
    &nbsp;
</p>

<p>
    <br />
    <meta content="20130307;3513400" name="CHANGED" />
</p>
<style type="text/css">
<!-- 
        BODY,DIV,TABLE,THEAD,TBODY,TFOOT,TR,TH,TD,P { font-family:"Calibri"; font-size:x-small }
         --></style>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cols="10" frame="VOID" rules="NONE" style="width: 1126px; height: 1270px;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="310" />
        <col width="37" />
        <col width="60" />
        <col width="147" />
        <col width="134" />
        <col width="42" />
        <col width="55" />
        <col width="152" />
        <col width="332" />
        <col width="85" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="LEFT" bgcolor="#FF9900" height="23" style="border-top: 3px solid #969696; border-bottom: 3px solid #969696; border-left: 3px solid #969696; border-right: 3px solid #969696" valign="MIDDLE" width="310">
                <b><font color="#000000">Qu&eacute; hacemos </font></b>
            </td>
            <td align="CENTER" bgcolor="#FF9900" style="border-top: 3px solid #969696; border-bottom: 3px solid #969696; border-left: 3px solid #969696; border-right: 3px solid #969696" valign="MIDDLE" width="37">
                <b><font color="#000000">curso</font></b>
            </td>
            <td align="CENTER" bgcolor="#FF9900" style="border-top: 3px solid #969696; border-bottom: 3px solid #969696; border-left: 3px solid #969696; border-right: 3px solid #969696" valign="MIDDLE" width="60">
                <b><font color="#000000">intensivo</font></b>
            </td>
            <td align="CENTER" bgcolor="#FF9900" style="border-top: 3px solid #969696; border-bottom: 3px solid #969696; border-left: 3px solid #969696; border-right: 3px solid #969696" valign="MIDDLE" width="147">
                <b><font color="#000000">fecha</font></b>
```

Comment: remove `width="1126px`" from table

Comment: Thanks! Can I make the container wider? You know, there's plenty f space on the sides... Thanks!  http://www.biomayeutika.org/que/

Comment: no thats your page padding dont play with that

Comment: Can I just change it in just this one page via inline CSS or something? It doesnt look good... Thanks Sahil

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust somewhere these values to adjust some look and feel

```
<colgroup>
        <col width="310" />
        <col width="37" />
        <col width="60" />
        <col width="147" />
        <col width="134" />
        <col width="42" />
        <col width="55" />
        <col width="152" />
        <col width="332" />
        <col width="85" />
    </colgroup>
```

adjust the widths manually

Comment: Thanks Sahil! but im going to try changing the padding anyway... Thanks!